# Gensim word2vec most_similar filtering by # prefix

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I have a word2vec model trained on twitter. I imported it into gensim using

```py
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./twitter.txt', binary=False)
```

I would like to use a function similar to this one:

```py
word_vectors.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'])
```

to show the most similar words, but I want to restrict the results to words that start with a hashtag.
Can somebody please give explain how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Gensim indexer doesn't support filtering while querying for neighbors. But you can do the filtering yourself:

```py
[item for item in word_vectors.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], 
                                            negative=['man'], 
                                            topn=1000) 
      if item[0].startswith('#')]
```